How can I insert data in access using vb.net
I'm trying to insert data in MS Access it but when I try to open my database the data isn't there. I'm a beginner in using vb.net and database
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\School\DBLC.accdb"
        con.Open()

        Dim query As String
        query = "INSERT INTO LC ([Name of Applicant], [Address of Applicant], [Contact of Applicant]) VALUES (@NameApp, @AddressApp, @ContactApp)"

        Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameApp", txtboxNameApp.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressApp", txtboxAddressApp.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactApp", txtboxContactApp.Text)

        MsgBox("New record added!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Convert.ToString(ex))
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


You should be awar ethat both of these technologies are pretty old. Access as a local database.... yeah maybe. VB.Net? I suggest you C# as there are way more examples.

I suggest you do two things: 1.Step through your code line by line: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp 2. Be more specific about "the data isn't there" - have you opened the table and it's completely empty?

If you temporariy remove the Try / Catch stuff completely it should be easier to debug as it will pop up the debugger if there is an error

Try command.ExecuteNonQuery() after you add your parameters. Unless you are working with an existing Access database, I echo the advice of the others, you would be better off long term using Sqlite (or Sql Server) with C#

Pretty much any tutorial on ADO.NET would have answered your question. I just searched the web for "how to insert data into access using an oledbcommand" and the very first result was a question on this very site that shows the solution. It's a C# question but it should be obvious what the solution is because the code is basically the same but with semicolons at the end. ALWAYS do what you can to answer a question for yourself first, which ALWAYS involves searching the web.

You code setups up the SQL, your code sets up the parameters, but then does not execute the command you created. You also don't have any
Hence, this code should work:
        Dim strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\School\DBLC.accdb"

        Dim query As String
        query = "INSERT INTO LC ([Name of Applicant], [Address of Applicant], [Contact of Applicant]) 
                 VALUES (@NameApp, @AddressApp, @ContactApp)"


        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(strCon)
            conn.Open()

            Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)

                command.Parameters.Add("@NameApp", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtboxNameApp.Text
                command.Parameters.Add("@AddressApp", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtboxAddressApp.Text)
                command.Parameters.Add("@ContactApp", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtboxContactApp.Text)

                command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using

        End Using

        MsgBox("New record added!")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Convert.ToString(ex))
    End Try

So, you are missing the "execute" of the command object you created.
And note above how we warp the connection and command object in using statements, as that ensures that everything is cleaned up, disposed, and the connection is automatic closed.
